# I updated my ipython notebook gist, but why didn't nbviewer update?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gist

I updated an ipython notebook gist here:

https://gist.github.com/rsignell-usgs/aa12c2b5e8a448bda780

but the nbviewer link here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/aa12c2b5e8a448bda780

is still displaying my old notebook.   I tried refreshing clearing the browser cache, but it still displays the old notebook.

Shouldn't it update?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is an [nbviewer
FAQ](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/faq#why-is-nbviewer-showing-an-outdated-version-of-my-notebook).

Basically it takes about 10 minutes to update, but if you want to
force it, you can add `?flush_cache=true` to the nbviewer URL.

So try doing this:

```
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/aa12c2b5e8a448bda780?flush_cache=true
```

Comment: +1.

This answer works for .ipynb notebooks sourced from a GitHub repo, like

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/your-username/some_repo/blob/master/notebook.ipynb?flush_cache=true

Comment: didn't work my NBViewer [link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/YousefSaber/Jupyter-Noteboos/blob/master/Julia%20Input.ipynb?flush_cache=true)
and my github [link](https://github.com/YousefSaber/Jupyter-Noteboos/blob/master/Julia%20Input.ipynb)

Comment: Works with `?flush_cache=True` rather than `true`.

Comment: This solution no longer works. `?flush_cache=True` only refresh once, then when I change the Jupiter notebook in GitHub again, it has no effect and have been stuck with the old version more than 1 hour.

Comment: It did not work for me as well. nbviewer link did not refresh after 10 mins also.

Comment: **NOTE** A work around that works to see how the current version will eventually render via nbviewer was posted [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/issues/914#issuecomment-939112741). It involves using the raw link that includes the full commit SHA. I detail how to get that for both gists and a standard GitHub repo in the last paragraph, [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/markdown-code-snippets-not-rendering-after-uploading-notebook-to-github/14480/2?u=fomightez).